# Decay rate of least eigenvalue of Gram matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, hilbert-spaces, lebesgue-integral

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space with inner product $\langle,\rangle$. Let $\mathcal{B}=\{\phi_i\}_{i=1}^\infty\subseteq H$ be a linearly independent set with $\|\phi_i\|=1$. Consider the matrices $A^p=(\langle \phi_i,\phi_j\rangle )_{1\leq i,j\leq p}$ of size $p\times p$, for $p\geq1$. Each matrix $A^p$ is symmetric and positive definite, and it corresponds to the Gram matrix of the set $\{\phi_i\}_{i=1}^p$. Let $\lambda_p>0$ be the minimum eigenvalue of $A^p$, for $p\geq1$. My question is whether $\lim_{p\rightarrow\infty} \lambda_p=0$ at polynomial or exponential rate.

In particular, take $H=L^2_w(I)$ as the weighted $L^2$ space, where $I\subseteq\mathbb{R}$:
$$ L_w^2(I)=\{\phi:I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}:\,\|\phi\|^2=\int_I \phi(x)^2w(x)\,dx<\infty\}. $$
It is assumed that $x^i\in H$ for all $i\geq0$. Consider the linearly independent set $\mathcal{B}=\{\phi_i\}_{i=1}^\infty\subseteq H$ defined as $\phi_i(x)=x^{i-1}/\|x^{i-1}\|$, $i\geq1$. Define $A^p=(\langle \phi_i,\phi_j\rangle )_{1\leq i,j\leq p}$. My question is whether $\lim_{p\rightarrow\infty} \lambda_p=0$ at polynomial or exponential rate.

Another question is whether there is a simple lower bound for each $\lambda_p$ in this case, in terms of the entries of $A^p$, but which does not involve $\det(A^p)$.

Comment: As daw cleverly showed, considering the general case is useless. To obtain estimates for your particular polynomial system $\phi_i$ it would be great to have some information on the orthogonal polynomials associated to $w$. Is your $w$ explicit?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro In the cases I am working with, the weight $w$ is a probability density function. For example, $I=\mathbb{R}$ and $w(x)=(1/\sqrt{2\pi})e^{-x^2/2}$, $I=(-1,1)$ and $w(x)=(1/2)1_{(-1,1)}(x)$, etc.

Comment: I recommend opening another post, perhaps on Math Overflow, containing only the question in the "In particular..." paragraph. (Of course, add all the context and examples you think may be useful, and a link to the present post). Do specify that $w$ is an arbitrary PDF. It would be great if you could include some computations on a specific example, such as the case of $I=(-1, 1)$ with $w(x)=1$. As is, the question is closed by the (disappointing) example by daw.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I asked the new question in Math Overflow: [https://mathoverflow.net/questions/299643/decay-rate-of-least-eigenvalue-of-gram-matrices](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/299643/decay-rate-of-least-eigenvalue-of-gram-matrices).

Answer (score 2):

This depends on your choice of $(\phi_i)$. If $(\phi_i)$ are orthonormal, then $\lambda_p=1$ for all $p$.

Take $H=l^2$. Define $\phi_1:=e_1$, $\phi_k:=\frac1{\sqrt{1+a_k^2}}e_1 + a_ke_k$. Then the eigenvalues of 
$$
\pmatrix{ 1 & \frac1{\sqrt{1+a_k^2}} \\ \frac1{\sqrt{1+a_k^2}} & \frac{a_k^2}{\sqrt{1+a_k^2}}}
$$
are upper bounds of $\lambda_p$  for $k\le p$. The smallest eigenvalue of this matrix is bounded above by $\frac{a_k^2}{\sqrt{1+a_k^2}}$. This follows from Cauchy eigenvalue interlacing theorem. Hence the decay rate of $\lambda_p$ can be arbitrarily fast.

In fact, constructing basis like 
$$
\phi_{2k}=e_{2k}, \quad \phi_{2k+1} = \frac1{\sqrt{1+a_k^2}} (e_{2k} + a_k e_{2k+1}),
$$
you can prescribe any decay rate of $\lambda_p$.

Comment: Ok, so I understand that, in a general Hilbert space $H$, the decay rate can be arbitrarily fast. What about the particular case of $H=L^2_w(I)$ ?

Comment: Could you please explain how to apply this "interlacing theorem"? [Is this what you are talking about](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem#Cauchy_interlacing_theorem)? Thank you

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I think one has to take a matrix $P$ of size $p\times 2$ with entries $P_{11}=1$, $P_{k2}=1$, $P_{ij}=0$ otherwise, in [this theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem#Cauchy_interlacing_theorem). Then $B=P^t AP$ is the $2\times 2$ matrix from the answer above.

Comment: @user39756: Thank you for the explanation.